# Replacing a quadrilateral with a square generated from PIL.QUAD

Tags: python-imaging-library

I am working on a computer vision problem involving some basic transformations and could use your help.

### Input image:

[image: huawei_0001_01-before transform]

### Transformed image

[image: huawei_0001_01]

I understand that we take this quadrilateral and tilt it and stretch it to obtain a rectangle:
[image: extracted]

I am wondering **by what ratio does the quadrilateral get stretched to produce the rectangle**? **By what angle is the quadrilateral tilted to get the square**? For example, if we had to replace the quadrilateral section by the transformed image (i.e replace image 3 with image 2), what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phew! I figured this out using this helpful answer at [Merging perspective corrected image with transparent background template image using PILLOW [PIL, Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227501/merging-perspective-corrected-image-with-transparent-background-template-image-u)

While you use QUAD to go from `quadrilateral` to `rectangle`, you can use perspective to go back from `rectangle` to `quadrilateral`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from itertools import chain
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='image2') as cover, Image(filename='image3') as template:
    w, h = cover.size
    cover.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'
    source_points = (
        (0, 0),
        (w, 0),
        (w, h),
        (0, h)
    )
    destination_points = (
        (628+78.37203406,  35.24937345),
        (628+577.65062655,  62.72203406),
        (628+550.17796594, 562.00062655),
        (628+50.89937345, 534.52796594)
    )
    order = chain.from_iterable(zip(source_points, destination_points))
    arguments = list(chain.from_iterable(order))
    cover.distort('perspective', arguments)

    # Overlay cover onto template and save
    template.composite(cover,left=0,top=0)
    template.save(filename='result.png')
```

Comment: Well done - thank you for sharing back with the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! I have a follow up question. How would I superimpose an image with the edges slightly blurred? Basically `template.composite(cover,left=0,top=0)` but with, say, a Gaussian Blur applied to the edges?

Comment: There are several folk on StackOverflow who can answer that better than I can, so, as questions (and answers) are free on Stack, I would encourage you to ask a new question specific to that aspect. By all means click the `share` button under this original question to get a URL and copy and paste that as a link in your new question so folks can see where we started and where we are going. Be sure to add the `imagemagick` and `wand` tags if you are using **wand**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. : )

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell - I haven't heard back on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276080/blending-the-edges-of-an-overlaid-image-using-python. Any thoughts on making it more visible?