# how do I merged an image into another image

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library, imagemagick, image-stitching, compositing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxQMr.png)

Hello, StackOverflow community!

I am currently embarking on a project that involves image merging. Specifically, my aim is to develop a feature where the user can upload an image and merge it with a selected template to create a single, realistic-looking output. The functionality should look like this:

- On the left side of the UI, the user uploads an image.
- On the right side, the user selects a provided template.
- Upon selection, the user's image merges with the template.
- The result is a merged, realistic image ready for download.

Please note that I'm not necessarily searching for an exact solution, but more so guidance or resources that can help me kickstart this endeavor. If you could provide any references, such as relevant GitHub repositories, libraries, or even specific keywords to streamline my Google search, it would be greatly appreciated.

In addition, can we handle image with transparent background?

- I tried google on my own
- I tried asking others

Comment: you can use the OpenCV library in Python. Have a look at this [project](https://towardsdatascience.com/background-removal-with-python-b61671d1508a)

Comment: Define "realistic"? Like a picture of a restaurant and a picture of a person, and you produce a picture of the person sitting at a table? Or it it just putting two images together? If the former, how do you intend to deal with pictures with incompatible perspective and lighting direction?

Comment: You can develop the GUI/web interface extremely quickly with `streamlit` You can distort the uploaded image to match the template like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229729/2836621

Comment: @xenoid just putting two images together. I don't think I need to adjust the lighting at this moment. definition of realistic is that: from users' perspective, I can't tell if it is a computer produced image or it is a real product image. it is a little subjective. not sure how I should define that. Like those amazon product image, it is photoshoped but it also looks real.

Comment: @herokuuse But that's exactly the problem. If you slap two random images together it looks fake due to mismatched color balance, perspective, and lighting. And in some case the insertion is one into the other is more complicated, because it must be in front of some element and behind others... Try your concept with Gimp/Photoshop before you try to code it...